# Control over Image scaling algorithm

Tags: java, image, javafx, java-8

I am trying to rewrite a Swing image viewer in JavaFX, however the scaling algorithm used by the JavaFX Image constructor is of very low quality. Unfortunately I have to rely on resizing the image in the constructor, because some of the pictures are too big to be loaded fully in memory for JavaFX (even though it used to work in Swing).

Here's a comparison. On the left, using `BufferedImage.drawImage` to downscale a picture and rendering it with `Graphics.drawImage` in `paintComponent` (using antialias rendering hint) and on the right the same picture loaded at the same downscaled resolution through the JavaFX Image constructor (smooth is set to true).

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2vY8.png)

As you can see the JavaFX downscaling algorithm introduces a form of sawtooth effect. How could I remedy this? I imagine the problem comes from the fact that the image is not fully loaded in memory but it seems I have no other choice.

Here's a code that will generate the comparison. Using the following [picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Grace_match_junior_cricket_ball.jpg) as an example.

```
public static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage img, int width, int height) {
  int imageType = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE)
        ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
  BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);
  Graphics2D context = scaled.createGraphics();
  context.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, 
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
  context.dispose();
  return scaled;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
  // Load full image in memory, downscale using BufferedImage
  Image image1 = new Image("file:4000x3600.jpg");
  BufferedImage bimg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image1, null);
  bimg = scale(bimg, 600, 600);
  image1 = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimg, null);

  // Downscale in the Image constructor, saves memory
  Image image2 = new Image("file:4000x3600.jpg", 600, 600, false, true);

  AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
  ImageView view1 = new ImageView(image1);
  view1.setLayoutX(0.0);
  view1.setLayoutY(0.0);

  ImageView view2 = new ImageView(image2);
  view2.setLayoutX(600.0);
  view2.setLayoutY(0.0);

  root.getChildren().add(view1);
  root.getChildren().add(view2);
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 600);
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] showing the two approaches?

Comment: Question edited with example code and comparison.

Comment: "*some of the pictures are too big to be loaded fully in memory for JavaFX (even though it used to work in Swing)*" Can you provide these pictures?

Comment: Unfortunately not (they are copyrighted) but the root of this memory issue is the inability to allocate enough heap space with JavaFX. Running a Swing application using -Xmx2g works correctly, but with JavaFX that much memory cannot be allocated by the JVM (x64 JVM using 16G RAM).

Comment: I don't see why there would be a difference in the memory allocation of the JVM between Swing and JavaFX. Sounds like a bug, I would [submit it](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/). If your image is 4000x3600 = 14.4Mil pixels and each pixel takes 4 bytes (rgba), then that's 57.6MB, which is really not a lot in any case. Are you getting an OOM exception?

Comment: As for the scaling algorithm, look at graphic's `com.sun.javafx.iio.jpeg.JPEGImageLoader` and `com.sun.javafx.iio.common.SmoothMinifier`. You can try to `--patch-module` to replace these (whichever you need) with your own version and see if that works for you.

Comment: I've just noticed that the allocation error only happens when executing the project through NetBeans (Error occurred during initialization of VM. Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap) but works fine when running `java -jar` from the command line. So there's that. Also patching does seem to be the only way to go about it sadly, I suppose this answers the original question.